# WAR in single Tomcat instance and multiple ports

Tags: tomcat, deployment, war

Suppose I have a single WAR deployed in a single Tomcat instance. The WAR contains two servlets: one for client requests and another for administration. Now I would like to run those servlets on different ports. Can I do that using the same single WAR and single Tomcat instance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to make tomcat listen on two different ports for HTTP but there is only one container. So I don't think so.